# Take the user input of numbers and print equivalent in the form of a -

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to take the user's input (numbers separated by commas, e.g., `"5,8,11"`), and return the equivalent number of `"-"`s. For example, if the user inputs `"4,2,4,5"`, then the output should be the following:

```
----
--
----
-----
```

with each on a new line. I need to take an input string, split it at the commas, which will turn it into an array, and then iterate through the array and print the amount of commas per element.

I tried this,

```
puts "Enter some numbers"
input = gets.chomp

input.split(',')

input.each do |times|
  puts "-" * times
end
```

which returns a `noMethodError`. I'm not sure where I am wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to iterate over `input.split(',')` not `input` :)

Comment: "I'm not sure where I am wrong." – The error message *tells* you where you are wrong. It includes the exact position of the error in the source code, the exact position of the error in the dynamic execution stack of the program, the object, and the name of the method. Since you are not telling us any of those, there is no way to help you, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

You need integers for that. Try

```
input = gets.chomp.split(',').map(&:to_i)
```

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things...

```
input.split(',')
```

This DOES split input, but it doesn't change the contents of the input variable.

What would work...

```
input = input.split(',')
```

Secondly, the result will be an array of strings, not integers, so better would be...

```
input = input.split(',').map(&:to_i)
```

This will map the string array into an integer array

Comment: Ah I see! Thanks for pointing out the difference with the .split